# Select a part of a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, substring

I have a MySQL table with a string column as,

```
ID       String                                                                                        
-----   -----------------------------------------
1        {"Type":"new", "Node":"{Status=New, Properties=[{PropertyValue=Samp, PropertyRefernceTypeID=1, PropertyTypeID=26}, {PropertyValue=25, PropertyRefernceTypeID=1, PropertyTypeID=33}]}"}
2        {Type":"new", "Node":"{Status=New, Properties=[{PropertyValue=25, PropertyRefernceTypeID=1, PropertyTypeID=33}, {PropertyValue=168-3, PropertyRefernceTypeID=1, PropertyTypeID=103}]}"}
```

Now how can I select only the `PropertyValue` of `PropertyTypeID=33` in MySQL select Query? It is possible by using `substring()` method only if the length of all the strings are equal but in my case the length may vary for different ids.

Comment: you do it in your application mysql is not good with string manipulation

Comment: Did you create the table like this or are you trying to fix it?

Comment: I have the table which stores the json as a string.

Comment: What JSON is this ? It is not valid.

Comment: Do you need just that specific value or any value in the string?

Comment: @mpsbhat, you shouldn't store it as JSON (or whatever this is) in the database.  You need to research database normalization then you wouldn't have this trouble.

Comment: updated the valid json format @ Lorenz

Comment: Specific value @Mascaro since my string have the length of about 1000

Comment: Only the first one in each string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why it is considered bad practice to store JSON, serialized arrays/objects, or just multiple values in a database field, unless for some reason you would never need anything inside it.

The field should always be atomic.  You should follow database normalization guidelines.

Therefore your database should be something like:

```
ID | PropertyValue | PropertyReferenceTypeID |  ProductTypeID
```

Then you would never have this problem, you would just do `SELECT PropertyValue FROM Properties WHERE ID=1`

But for now, to avoid this trouble, if you are using an app language, just get the string and decode it.  For example, in PHP:

```
$array = json_decode($str);
$PropertyValue = $arr['Node']['Properties']['PropertyValue'];
```

P.S.  Your json still isn't completely valid with it's nesting.